# Accessing a specific VBA code module using C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am creating workbooks from a template. The template already has the required code modules in it. I am trying to get a reference to one of the code modules, the one that the code needs to be imported to (the code is always different so having a .bas file wont work here as there would be hundreds of them).

I can easily access a new code module using

```
var codeModule = excelWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```

But I need to access the existing "Methods" code module in the instantiated workbook variable

```
 //initialize the Excel application and make it invisible to the user.
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application
        {
            UserControl = false,
            Visible = false
        };

        //Create the Excel workbook and worksheet - and give the worksheet a name.
        var excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(TemplateFilePath);
        excelWorkbook.Author = Acknowledgements.Author;
        var bookPath = excelWorkbook.Path;

        //add the macro code to the excel workbook here in the Methods module.
       //this adds a new module, how do I access an existing one?
        var codeModule = excelWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```

I could just loop through the modules and get it by testing name equality but there must be a way to retrieve it in one line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241522(v=vs.60).aspx) method of the [VBComponents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443983(v=vs.60).aspx) collection to retrieve an existing VBComponent by name or numeric index:

```
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

VBIDE.VBComponent component = excelWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("Methods");
VBIDE.CodeModule module = component.CodeModule;
```

Comment: Just figured that out and tested. Thank you for confirming

Comment: Where does the VBIDE come from? Apparently it is not part of Microsoft.VBE.Interop or Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: @ScottinTexas: I don't remember exactly where. Microsoft.Vbe.Interop shows up as VBIDE in Solution Explorer, but there's no VBIDE namespace. Maybe I had added `using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;`